# Joomla! 2.5 does not show the modules in my template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am doing a Joomla! 2.5 project

I put this `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="izquierdo" style="none"/>` and don´t show me nothing.

the positions in my template is this

```
<positions>
    <position>izquierdo</position>
    <position>extranet</position>
    <position>menuPrincipal</position>
```

the status of this module is public.

Any idea, am I miss something?

Hi, I try to show the module

Comment: Do you want to hide the module ? or the module is not being shown ? Deseas ver u ocultar el módulo ?

Comment: removed my answer as I thought you were trying to hide a module. Try changing `type="modules"` to `type="module"`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link for creating module position.
Briefly explained here: http://www.zootemplate.com/joomla-tutorials/how-to-make-position-in-joomla.html

Answer (score 0):

[Module positions](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_positions)

[How do you add a new module position](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position?)

[Finding module positions on any given page](http://docs.joomla.org/Finding_module_positions_on_any_given_page)

You should be fine if you follow the steps. If you come across any problems please ask them here.